# Запятая в наименовании

Tags: запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Аппарат дробильно-бурильный(,) автоматический(,) для твёрдых пород"?

Мне здесь запятые кажутся лишними, поскольку нет перечислений равнозначных элементов. У автоматического равнозначные "ручной" и "полуавтоматический", например, но точно не "дробильно-бурильный". Если поставить запятую между "дробильно-бурильный" и "автоматический", то звучит как-то странно: "Аппарат дробильно-бурильный (ПАУЗА) автоматический для твёрдых пород". Как бы "автоматический" он только для твёрдых пород. Но идея-то в том, что он в принципе автоматический, аппарат этот.

Благодарю!